# How to upload images from a server and switch images with a seekbar without the previous image disappearing?

Tags: java, android, image, animation, picasso

I have been commissioned by the Autonomous University of Barcelona to make an app that shows images of the microscope stage of a mineral sample.

Specifically I have photos of the same sample spaced by a five degree turn (72 images).
[Downloaded from the AUB website](https://ddd.uab.cat/record/190567?ln=ca).

Below the image there has to be a seekbar and the images have to be loaded as it moves, giving the impression that the microscope stage is rotating.

I have tried it with Picasso:

```
public class FichaOpacos extends AppCompatActivity {
private String urlParalelos;
private ImageView platina;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ficha_opacos);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String id = intent.getStringExtra("id");
    Database myDb = new Database(this);
    String mineral = myDb.getMineral(id);
    platina = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.platina);
    urlParalelos = myDb.getURL1(mineral);
    myDb.closeDatabase();
    String urlInicialParalelos= urlParalelos+ "1.jpg";
    Picasso.get().load(urlInicialParalelos).into(platina);
    SeekBar seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seek);
    seekBar.setProgress(0);
    seekBar.incrementProgressBy(1);
    seekBar.setMax(71);
    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String urlFinalParalelos = urlParalelos+ String.valueOf(progress+1) + ".jpg";
            Picasso.get().load(urlFinalParalelos).into(platina);

        }
    });


}
}
```

The problem is that in the transition between images the image disappears and then after milliseconds the next one appears, not giving the impression that you are looking at a rotating microscope stage.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

How could I get the desired effect?

I imagine I need an animation that keeps the previous image until the next image is displayed, but I have never worked with animations and would not know how to implement it.

Comment: I would say that you are simply replacing the painted components image by replacing the filename source that is loaded by the component itself from one of its methods , rather than painting it onto the GUI component from a java.awt.image.BufferedImage g Graphics reference handing the pixel values to the components g Graphics reference to paint. In any case it appears the image may not be fitting the size or shape of the screen it is displayed, causing some feature of the software to stall while resizing.

Comment: Why not build a system from javax.imageio.IIOImage , resize all images to the same size if they are not the same and obtain the Raster for the image and keep it separate linked to painting the GUI screen, and simply load the chosen or next image into a second Raster and when it is time to change replace the main Raster for the gui component with the second one and repaint the screen. Some of that appears network speed over internet.

Comment: @Samuel Marchant I am a newbie, and could not realize your solution. I could just try to implement it if you post your soulution as an answer. The app is going to include the option to download all the images from the server and work with no connection, but they want that the app also works without having the images stored in the internal memory. For the moment the code in my answer works. The only problem is it takes 10 seconds in my Samsung Galaxy A50 to load the 72 images from the server.

Comment: Then make 72 separate classes with java.net.HttpURLConnection   and put them on an array to download the images and in the class that has the controlling code loop over these classes to initialize them  in the constructor so they will somewhat concurrently get downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I have found that produces the expected result is to download the 72 images at the start of the activity.

In this way the images are available and load quickly and it seems that the microscope stage rotates.

The only drawback is that the user has to wait a few seconds to load the activity.

```
public class FichaOpacos extends AppCompatActivity {
private String urlParalelos;
private ImageView platina;
private ArrayList<Drawable> imagenes;
private ProgressDialog progress;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ficha_opacos);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String id = intent.getStringExtra("id");
    Database myDb = new Database(this);
    String mineral = myDb.getMineral(id);
    platina = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.platina);
    urlParalelos = myDb.getURL1(mineral);
    myDb.closeDatabase();
    String urlInicialParalelos = urlParalelos + "1.jpg";
    Picasso.get().load(urlInicialParalelos).into(platina);
    SeekBar seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seek);
    seekBar.setProgress(0);
    seekBar.incrementProgressBy(1);
    seekBar.setMax(71);
    imagenes = new ArrayList<>();
    progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progress.setMessage("Loading images....");
    progress.show();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //doing long task
            try {
                for(int i= 0 ;i < 72; i++) {
                    imagenes.add(drawableFromUrl(urlParalelos + String.valueOf(i + 1) + ".jpg"));
                    float tantoporuno = (float)(i+1)/(float)72;
                    int porcentaje = Math.round(tantoporuno*100);
                    progress.setMessage("Loading..." + String.valueOf(porcentaje) + "%");
                    if (i==71) {
                        progress.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    platina.setImageDrawable(imagenes.get(progress));
                }
            }).start();
        }
    });
}
public static Drawable drawableFromUrl(String url) throws IOException {
    Bitmap x;
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
    connection.connect();
    InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
    x = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
    return new BitmapDrawable(Resources.getSystem(), x);
}
}
```